# CMD Command for copying, renaming and pasting

Tags: cmd

I was wondering if someone could give me a hand with a quick batch file.

I need a command to delete `TruTacDataCapture.exe` 
then copy `TruTacDataCapture.exe.Config` and rename it to `TruTacDataCapture.exe`, and then paste it into the same folder.

Comment: `move /Y "TruTacDataCapture.exe.Config" "TruTacDataCapture.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

In the windows terminal you can use MS-DOS commands

- [To copy](http://www.computerhope.com/copyhlp.htm)
- [To Delete](http://www.computerhope.com/delhlp.htm)
- [To Rename](http://www.computerhope.com/renamehl.htm)